# How can I use prepositions differently not normally?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-objects

I have seen some complex sentences, having complex grammar of prepositions.

For example:

> “T is the temperature **to which** the accumulated distillate stream, formed in previous effects, cools down **to** as it enters the flashing box.”

Why using **to which**?

cools down **to** What?

Sometimes I can't understand these kind of sentences... how can I understand and also use such sentences? Is there any reference for practice?

Comment: You should eliminate the second “to”; it is redundant.

Comment: The sentence is not for mine. I have copied it from a reference

Comment: @EnglishLearner Then you should say that you sometimes come _across_ (or _upon_) with these complex sentences. When you say that you sometimes _come up with_ them, that means you sometimes make them up yourself, which is presumably why James thought it was your own sentence.

Answer (score 3):

I have removed the adjectives and adverbials to clarify the structure, which is a relative phrase using the object of a preposition.  "___" indicates the trace that the pronoun is moved from.

1) *"T is the temperature **to which** the stream cools down **to** ___." -- This is ungrammatical because the preposition has been repeated.

2) "T is the temperature **which** the stream cools down **to** ___." -- This is a grammatical version, but it may confuse the listener if the trace is followed by a noun phrase (such as the gerund adverbial ", entering the box").

3) "T is the temperature **to which** the stream cools down ___." -- This is a grammatical version that moves the preposition along with the pronoun.

Comment: that is a good explanation, I suspect that what has been attempted is: 'to which...cools' + 'down to'. The whole use of 'down' is suspect when 'temperature' is included in the sentence.

Comment: 'Down' is quite compatible with 'temperature', but it is redundant with 'cool'.

Comment: ... which is what I meant by 'the sentence'.